# OpenSSL and PHP SHA256 digests differ

Tags: php, openssl, base64, sha256

I've trying to calculate the base64 encoded sha256 hash of some JavaScript at the command line using OpenSSL and via PHP.

```
cat test.js | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
(p5CrWBV6O1Xp7BlWwdVXTeGeSx3uo/IsNaYOIOblAZk=)

echo base64_encode(hash("sha256", "alert('Test');", true));
(2D7QyY5W4ziVZhF/vzeGy8oHgnz4TjqaoifV41mHi3c=)
```

The resulting base64 encoded values are not the same, but the input to each method is the same. Stepping back, the sha256 hash digests do not match before base64 encoding.

```
cat test.js | openssl dgst -sha256
(a790ab58157a3b55e9ec1956c1d5574de19e4b1deea3f22c35a60e20e6e50199)

echo hash("sha256", "alert('Test');");
(d83ed0c98e56e3389566117fbf3786cbca07827cf84e3a9aa227d5e359878b77)
```

I'm not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue in the end thanks to some support on Twitter.

When editing the JS file with nano, it was appending a newline character on the end. Editing the file using `nano -L test.js` resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`cat` is adding an extra newline character, which is going along for the ride in the digest. Try running the digest on the file directly:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary test.js | ...
```

Comment: `cat` does not add newline after the output